# Tuple unpack in assignment

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I would like to unpack a tuple in a python statement like so:

```
a = 5, *(6,7)
```

but this raises a `SyntaxError`. What is the cleanest way to achieve something like this?

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
a = tuple([5]+list((6,7)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just concatenate the tuples directly:

```
>>> a = (5,)+(6, 7)     
>>> a
(5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could do this!

Comment: @user545424 Python often surprises people by being oddly sane for a programming language.